# problem with my code trying to install plinkR2

Tags: r, genome

```
devtools::install_github("gabraham/plink2R/plink2R")
error from R:
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/lucas/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpiCTWGN/file52a43a9a310c/plink2R_1.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we can't solve for it.

Answer (score 0):

This has been an open issue in their github repository,

https://github.com/gabraham/plink2R/issues/10

I would suggest continuing from there and reach out to the author of the said package. I tried it and it also failed in my end. It must be something in the `.cpp` files that they integrated in their package.